# javascript title on text field

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have HTML title Like this
http://s1.postimg.org/4ebyk3qwv/image.png

when I write this code:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("TL85_1_7").title = "Tooltip Example"
</script>
```

("TL85_1_7" - This is the Id of the element)

Hovering the element in first line shows the title e.g, "Pr Emp", "Pr Emp End". On the other lines hovering wont show the title.

any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div class="NODE" nowrap=""  style="left:273px;top:278px;width:46px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 46px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;"   id="TL85_1_5">Pr&nbsp;Emp</div>
<div class="NODE" nowrap=""  style="left:264px;top:297px;width:47px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 47px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;"   id="TL85_1_5">Start&nbsp;Dt</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your html structure ?

Comment: I edited with example of the html structure

Answer (score 1):

The id Should be unique in HTML page in your case you are assigning the same id to 2 nodes so JavaScript will return you the first id it found please change id to class then use this code.

```
<div class="NODE TL85_1_5" nowrap=""  style="left:273px;top:278px;width:46px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 46px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;" >Pr&nbsp;Emp</div>
<div class="NODE TL85_1_5" nowrap=""  style="left:264px;top:297px;width:47px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 47px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;" >Start&nbsp;Dt</div>
```

Now try this

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("TL85_1_5");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].title = "Tooltip Example";
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mabdullah353/jLs112fs)

Now the HTML is not in your control then the second solution is

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("NODE");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].id === "TL85_1_5")
      x[i].title = "Tooltip Example";
}
```

Here i am assuming that each div has the "Node" class

Comment: Thank you
But the HTML generate automatic by our system. is there a way to do it without change from Id the CLASS?

Comment: yes sure there is a way, let me give you another solution

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem

```
<div class="NODE" nowrap=""  style="left:502px;top:279px;width:36px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 36px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;"   id="TL85_1_7">Par14</div>
<div class="NODE" nowrap=""  style="left:510px;top:298px;width:20px;height:17px;z-index:5000; clip:rect(0px 20px 17px 0px);font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;"   id="TL85_1_7">Sw</div>
```

I have the same ID to 2 different elements.

the problem is that it automated page generated so I cant touch the HTML